# Method in enum type

Tags: javascript

Let say I have an enum like so:

```
const Days = {
  MONDAY: `MONDAY`,
  TUESDAY: `TUESDAY`,
  WEDNESDAY: `WEDNESDAY`
  //, etc.
};

var aDay = Days.MONDAY;
```

How do I implement, say a "next()" function that I could call simply like `aDay.next();` ?

EDIT: Here is what I did, following some of the advice I got in the comments. I wanted to create a parent class Enum so that I can define all my different enums in an elegant way and not have redundancy in my code. [Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GaetanL/sznc9fjm/107/). Please let me know how you feel about it and what I should modify:

```
class Enum {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  value() {
    return this.value;
  }

    get index() {
    // this.constructor returns the class DayOfWeek to call the static variable/function values
    return this.constructor.values.indexOf(this);
  }

  get next() {
    // this.constructor returns the class DayOfWeek to call the static variable/function values
    return this.constructor.values[(this.index + 1) % this.constructor.values.length];
  }

  get prev() {
    // this.constructor returns the class DayOfWeek to call the static variable/function values
    let unchecked = (this.index - 1) % this.constructor.values.length;
    return this.constructor.values[unchecked < 0 ? unchecked + this.constructor.values.length : unchecked];
  }
}

class DayOfWeek extends Enum {}

DayOfWeek.MONDAY =    new DayOfWeek("Monday");
DayOfWeek.TUESDAY =   new DayOfWeek("Tuesday");
DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY = new DayOfWeek("Wednesday");
DayOfWeek.THURSDAY =  new DayOfWeek("Thursday");
DayOfWeek.FRIDAY =    new DayOfWeek("Friday");
DayOfWeek.SATURDAY =  new DayOfWeek("Saturday");
DayOfWeek.SUNDAY =    new DayOfWeek("Sunday");
DayOfWeek.values = [DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY];
```

Comment: Try `Object.entries(Days)` and loop over them to get the key-value pairs.

Comment: But I want to put function inside the enum class so that I dont have to do treatment in the code using the enum. And I can't find the syntax to define a function inside my class.

Comment: I'm "thinking in Java" and I don't know how to translate that in JS.

Comment: I like the generic approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are targeting ES2015 or later something like this would work

```js
class DayOfWeek {
    constructor(index) {
        this.index = index;
        this.names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
        // TODO: Add validation that number is between 1 and 7
    }
    get name() {
        return this.names[this.index];
    }
    next() {
        let next = this.index + 1;
        if (next === 7) {
            next = 1;
        }
        return Days[this.names[next]];
    }
}
export class Days {
}
Days.Monday = new DayOfWeek(0);
Days.Tuesday = new DayOfWeek(1);
Days.Wednesday = new DayOfWeek(2);
Days.Thursday = new DayOfWeek(3);
Days.Friday = new DayOfWeek(4);
Days.Saturday = new DayOfWeek(5);
Days.Sunday = new DayOfWeek(6);
```

Or if you are using TypeScript you can write it like this then compile to ealier version of JS

```js
class DayOfWeek {
  private names: string[] = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
  constructor(private index: number) {
    // TODO: Add validation that number is between 1 and 7
  }

  public get name(): string {
    return this.names[this.index];
  }

  public next(): DayOfWeek {
    let next = this.index + 1;
    if(next === 7) {
      next = 1;
    }

    return Days[this.names[next]];
  }
}

export class Days {
  public static Monday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(0);
  public static Tuesday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(1);
  public static Wednesday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(2);
  public static Thursday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(3);
  public static Friday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(4);
  public static Saturday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(5); 
  public static Sunday: DayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek(6);  
}
```

Comment: I tweaked my code following on your advice, please let me know if you have any more advice?